# i18n of link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I do this:

```
<%= f.label t('voucher.new.accept_conditions', 
    :conditions => link_to(t('voucher.new.conditions'), '#')) %>
```

For some reason the output is escaped no matter what I do. I have done both .html_safe end raw() on every part of the statement but to no avail.

Can someone help out here? It is Rails 3.2.6.

Comment: Try to separate `label` and `link` with something like this: <%= f.label t(...) %> <%= link_to t(...), "#" %>

Comment: That only works if the link is the last part of the label text. It isn't here :-(

Comment: And what behavior do you expect on the view, can you please describe it?

Comment: I expect a label like "I accept the _conditions_ and the rules I signed up for". _conditions_ being the link.

Comment: Seems to be only it is not possible to pass html to `I18n.translate` method. I tried to escape and unescape it with different ways but there was no success.

Answer (score 1):

Just call .html_safe on the returned translation like so (I tried this in Rails 4.0.0):

```
t('voucher.new.accept_conditions', :conditions => link_to(t('voucher.new.conditions'), '#')).html_safe
```